# Suggest matrix $A$ with a maximal singular value of $5$

Tags: matrices, singular-values, matrix-norms

Suggest matrix $A \in M_{4x4}$ such that :

1. $\mbox{rank}(A) = 2$
2. $A$ is not diagonal
3. maximal singular value of $A$ is $5$

I have tried to guess some symmetric matrices without any luck .

Comment: Can you find a matrix in $M_{2\times2}$ with those requirements? That's easier, and pretty transferable.

Comment: if I find $A \in M_{2x2}$ such that $A^T*A = 5I$ could I say that the max singular value of A is $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: $M_{4x4}(\mathbb R)$? $M_{4x4}(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo could be either one

Comment: If you're asked to find $A$ with maximal singular value $5$, how can we say the max singular value of $A$ is $\sqrt5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D=diag(5,1,0,0)$, that way, the rank of $D$ would be $2$.

$QDQ^T$ would satisfy the first and the third condition if $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix.

In particular, you can pick $Q$ to be the hadamard matrix. I would leave the explicit construction to you.